# cheapest flight price through R

Tags: r

I'm trying to generate cheapest price output in R through this *url* (Also available in the code below):

***[Cheap Flights from MakeMyTrip](https://flights.makemytrip.com/makemytrip/search/O/O/E/1/0/0/S/V0/DEL_BOM_23-06-2017?contains=false&remove=)***

Though we can sort cheapest and highest price by clicking on 'PRICE' button on the *url* link.

Is there any way I can output cheapest flight price in R only?

This is my code so far:

```
library(rvest)
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
library(DBI)

url1 <-  
  'https://flights.makemytrip.com/makemytrip/search/O/O/E/1/0/0/S/V0/DEL_BOM_23-06-2017?contains=false&remove='

Var1 <- read_html(url1)
```

Comment: I was also looking through the Inspector through Firefox in the url  and found this <span class="num ng-binding">5,562</span>..  Is this something we have to use to get the cheapest flight Price?

Answer (score 1):

If you check the lower left of the filter menu on the page you will find the slider "Price Range". Here, the lowest price has the unique css selector "#min_price". However, crawling it with rvest is not possible as the `read_html`call is not reading the full page due to javascript.

However, you can download it via RSelenium using a more complicated approach. 
Note: This approach will be slow at the first time as RSelenium will install the required browsers (took me like 45 minutes). However, future applications will be performed instant.

```
library(RSelenium)
library(XML)
url1 <- "https://flights.makemytrip.com/makemytrip/search/O/O/E/1/0/0/S/V0/DEL_BOM_23-06-2017?contains=false&remove="

# Open Browser (slow at the first start)
rd <- rsDriver(browser = "phantomjs")

# Navigate to page
remDr <- rd[["client"]]
remDr$navigate(url1)

# Download price
elem <- remDr$findElement(using = "css selector", "#min_price")
elemtxt <- elem$getElementAttribute("outerHTML")[[1]]
price <- xpathSApply(htmlParse(elemtxt), "//*[@id='min_price']", xmlValue)

# Format price and output
price <- as.numeric(gsub(",", "", price))
cat("The cheapest flight costs:", price)
```

Comment: thank you @Niko . Quick question  I installed package using install.packages('RSelenium') Though I'm still getting this error > library(RSelenium)
Error in library(RSelenium) : there is no package called ‘RSelenium’   Can you please tell me what I'm doing wrong? Or is something else also is needed to be installed?

Comment: Sry I forgot that you have to install Selenium Server first. You will find it under http://www.seleniumhq.org/download/ 

Just follow the first link to install the "Selenium Server Standalone"

Comment: There is a binary version available but the source version is later:
          binary source needs_compilation
RSelenium  1.6.2  1.7.1             FALSE

Packages which are only available in source form, and may need compilation
  of C/C++/Fortran: ‘subprocess’ ‘semver’
  These will not be installed
installing the source packages ‘wdman’, ‘RSelenium’

ERROR: dependencies 'binman', 'subprocess', 'semver' are not available for package 'wdman'

Comment: You have to download the .jar file.

If RSelenium does not find it after the download you can go to your console (cmd) and type `java -jar selenium-server-standalone-x.xx.x.jar` in the respective folder.